# Issue with nginx rewrite rule for wordpress default search query

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm using nginx and I found some 404 errors for WordPress blog searches. I need to make a rewrite in nginx but I need help to do.

**Eg:**

```
404 URL
```

http://example.com/blog/?s=searchterm

Should be redirected to

http://example.com/?s=searchterm

Comment: If you need general help with this issue then perhaps the NGINX docs ( http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) or the search box above is a better place to start seeking your answers.

Comment: I tried the following rule, but still not working.  rewrite ^/blog/?s=(.+)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;  Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer as I am not familiar with nginx rewrite rules. I just thought that perhaps since this is a general question the documentation or search feature would have been able to find you an answer.